# OpenCart 3.0.2.0 URL added to meta title

Tags: opencart, title, meta, opencart-3

OpenCart seems to be randomly adding the start of my domain name to the meta title. I have no SEO extensions added and when I view source there is nothing obvious there that's causing this. Can someone help me as it seems to be hurting my SEO.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The random word being added as you can see in the image attached is boat as in boatlicenceplates.co.uk (I believe!)

Comment: Matthew, what should the URL be? "http://licenceplates.co.uk?"

Comment: The URL is correct at boatlicenceplates.co.uk. The problem is that the word boat is being added to the meta title and i need it gone.

Comment: What's your thoughts ? Any ideas ? I'm desperate to get this sorted.

Comment: Have you considered that this may be a crawling issue? You're right, there is no "- boat" in the meta on the page so it's weird that Google shows it. More weird is the fact that it doesn't happen on certain pages in the search results yet when you visit the pages, none contain that additional word

Comment: So what do you think it could be ? I'm seriously thinking of dumping opencart because of this.

Comment: Why don’t you login into your Google Webmaster tools and use the option to fetch a page as the Google bot and see if the Meta Title is the same on those affected URLs. Then you can determine whether the issue is Google or OpenCart

Comment: I will try this now

Comment: Ok we are now getting somewhere.

Comment: the word boat does appear on the meta title on fetch and render with webmaster tools. What's the next step ? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwMuu.png)

Comment: What URL were you fetching there? Notice how "Home" doesn't appear in any of your current titles? I even searched the store for the string "Home" and there were only two results, none of which matched the title of the page you appear to have fetched